# eFence/Duma for Windows

Tags: c++, windows, debugging

I would appreciate some help concerning a good way to debug invalid memory accesses on Windows. Being a Linux developer, I am a big fan of Valgrind. Even Duma and eFence are very efficient tools. But on Windows I am totally lost (WinXP/VS2008). I tried a lot of tools, tried to link my program against duma with no luck.

Here are the symptoms for the bug I am having:

- Crash in Release mode on some specific configurations (only the size of my data changes)
- When it doesn't crash in Release mode, the name of the test in the report is replaced by random characters. (I am using Boost.Test)
- Nothing in Debug mode, everything goes well

This definitely sounds like a invalid write/read somewhere, but debugging in Release mode is impossible, I need to reproduce the crash in Debug mode. Redefining the new operator and try to imitate the behavior of eFence/Duma was my best bet, but I am having troubles overriding it.

So far I tried:

- Dr.Memory
- GFlags
- AppVerifier
- Duma (cannot override malloc/etc..)

I'd be more than thankful if someone could give me a tip there because it's been a while since I am trying to resolve this issue.

Thanks in advance.